# Facebook Lead Ads server-side-only fetch

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to write a script on one of our backend servers that will run on an automated basis, log in to Facebook, and retrieve the leads from the Facebook Lead Ads api. I'm using the guide published here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/leads/v2.6

The difficulty I'm having is that in order to fetch the leads, the script will need the manage_pages permission. I attempted to apply for this by creating an "app" in Facebook's Developer interface, and by requesting approval for the manage_pages permission, but my request was denied because the screencast didn't show how the "app" worked, and they weren't able to see a clear method to "log in".

Since this script will never be seen or accessed by end-users, and the login process is being handled entirely by the server-side script, I'm not sure how to go about getting approval for this. We're not using Facebook API's in any other way right now and we don't have any plans for writing user-facing apps. The documentation and examples on Facebook's site all seem geared toward people who are writing user-facing apps and it's not clear how to proceed in our case.

Is there a best practice for getting approval for permissions on server-side-only apps that use Facebook APIs? Or is this something that people just don't do?

Comment: So, Peter, did you found how to achieve this? If so, share with us!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have admin permissions on the page under which the leads are generated, you can just generate access tokens with manage_pages and ads_management permission and use this token to retrieve the leads.

You can generate an access token with the mentioned scope even if the app you are using to make the api call doesn't have these permissions.

Try using the Graph API Explorer to test this out - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explore

Select any ads api app that you have created from the drop down and click on generate use token button. Select the ads_management and manage_pages checkboxes when generating the token and use this to then query /leads of /leads.

Answer (score 0):

You can too get a 'Extend Access Token'.

On https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/ gerate a Token. With the Token paste on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ and click on 'Extend Access Token'. This Token will is validate to next 60 days.